# Error while calling Member function with function pointer

Tags: c++

```
Class B
{
public:
  void fun(int i){}
};
typedef std::function<void(int)> fPtr;
class C
{
public:
  void fun1(fptr handle){}
};
class A
{

public:
  B object;
  C object1;
  void temp()
{
 object1.fun1(&B::fun);
}

};
```

I am trying to call fun1() as given but it gives compiler error. whats the correct way of calling it?

Comment: `object` and `object1` are seriously the best names you could come up with to make a clear and easy-to-follow example?

Comment: And `fPtr` is also a terribly confusing name, since nothing about the type is in any way pointer-like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you want to call something like:

```
object1.fun1([this](int n){object.fun(n);});
```

Alternatively:

```
object1.fun1(std::bind(&B::fun, &object, std::placeholders::_1));
```